# Solar Panel Tilt Angle Transfer Function of Solar Tracker with Electro-Pneumatic

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, simulink

I have a project about single axis solar tracker control system simulation based on PID Controller with simulink. So far, I already manage to derive transfer function for the actuator (electro-pneumatic actuator). But I can't find transfer function for the '**plant**', that is solar panel, which need **stroke displacement** as input and solar panel **tilt angle** as the output. Does anyone here know how to find it or have any journal/article reference about this?

Thanks

P.S Here are my works so far
[image: Control Block Diagram]
[image: Actuator Transfer Function]
[image: Electro-Pneumatic Parameters]

My Journal Reference:
https://node1.123dok.com/dt01pdf/123dok_us/001/644/1644219.pdf.pdf?X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=7PKKQ3DUV8RG19BL%2F20230318%2F%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230318T084731Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=600&X-Amz-Signature=d9637a1541d93a937a4583059f1ba247e8ada8bf8a3b54845420d34f774f173d

Comment: It depends on the mechanical linkage between the actuator and the panel. There is no one value for this - it’s all up to the design engineer to resolve.

Comment: This is steam era stuff, not electronics. Possibly useful search term : four bar linkage design (some of the most interesting work dates back to James Watt!)